# how to use child standard object data in the personalized mail while your journey salesforce data entry event is on parent object

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, automationstudio, email-studio

I am creating a journey for which the entry event is a salesforce data event on a contact object.
But I have to use child object field data in the mail to personalize the mail.

For example

```
Parent object: Contact
Fields: Firstname, Lastname, Email, ContactId
```

```
Child object: Team
Fields: TeamId, TeamName, ContactId(lookup)
```

So how I can use the Team object data in the mail while journey's entry event is salesforce data on contact object?

I tried with ampscript following this article: [Personalize email using standard object](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_create_personalized_triggered_send.htm&type=5)

I have used the similar code mentioned in the link given above.But I am getting these errors.

> Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: SObject

> Error 2: Script SET Statement Invalid An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: RecordId MemberID: JobID: 0 An unrecognized expression appears in a script block. Script Expression: RecordId. Invalid Content: Set @TeamRecordId = RecordId There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative.

> Error 3: Script SET Statement Invalid An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: RetrieveSalesforceObjects(SObject,'TeamName,TeamId','Id', '=', RecordId) The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client.

Comment: please share your code for us to give an informed answer. - "similar to X" is too broad a description of what you've done so far. At this stage what I can say the solution is probably... similar to the working example? If you get what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to figure out what was wrong. Please check the code right below that might help others.

```
%%[
var @Rows, @Row, @ContactId, @TeamID, @Name 
set @ContactId= ContactId
set @Rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Team" , "TeamId, Name", "ContactId", "=", @ContactId)
If RowCount(@Rows) > 0 then
Set @Row = Row(@Rows, 1)
Set @TeamId= FIELD(@Row, "TeamId")
Set @Name = FIELD(@Row, "Name")
endif
]%%
```

For more information https://ampscript.guide/retrievesalesforceobjects/